# Is `super` statically bound in classes?

Tags: scala, class, traits

I am reading the chapter about traits in "Programming in Scala" by Martin Odersky et al (2ed) and I am puzzled by a statement that `super` in class in statically bound, unlike in trait, where it is dynamically bound (p.220).

I understand this statement, but when it comes to example like this one:

```
val queue = (new BasicIntQueue with Incrementing with Filtering)
```

on p.229 or entire explanation of linearization (p.234) it seems to me, that `super` cannot be statically bound, because otherwise stacking traits would not be possible -- i.e. when class "starts" the chain of calling of stacked method with `super` already resolved, it would hit direct class parent no matter what user added to the stack of traits.

What am I missing? :-) Is `super` really statically bound to its parent?

Comment: When you call `super` method in a stacked class, it always calls one specific method in one of the parent traits, right? And the compiler knows the exact static type of the object, including all the traits it inherits. So nothing prevents static dispatch here, as far as I can see.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, ad. "method in stacked class". This method comes from the class `BasicIntQueue`, the method is written and compiled for  that class without knowing how it will be used in future. And yet `super` is rerouted. As I said, maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: While this method does come from `BasicIntQueue`, it is overridden in each of the stackable trait which means that each trait also contains this method. You can find them in `javap` output easily. Anyway, there is no such thing as static dispatch in Java bytecode for non-static methods. The bytecode will contain `invokevirtual` for regular methods and `invokeinterface` for interface methods (`invokespecial` for constructors and `invokedynamic` for something else). These methods still have to be resolved against the virtual table unless some optimization like inlining is used.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, traits are compiled separately and I am interested in perspective what comes **from** the method. So in short, you state that the description is incorrect, and `super` for class is dispatched dynamically in Scala?

Comment: That's exactly the reason I didn't write an answer - I'm somewhat confused by the terminology and not sure that we're talking about the same thing :) But yes, AFAIU on JVM everything is dispatched dynamically unless optimized, there is no such thing as static dispatch like that in C++ with non-virtual methods. The closest thing to static dispatch is `invokestatic` for static methods, but naturally it is not used with traits.

Comment: The author probably meant that the compiler always knows which trait the method comes from. Maybe there are some optimizations on scalac level which can take advantage of this information.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, as for your 2nd comment, I am almost sure it is not the case, because it is the point you can mix-in traits as you like (hence the name -- stack of traits).

Comment: The fact that you can mix traits as you like does not preclude the compiler from knowing the type of each variable (and hence from knowing exactly on which trait the method should be called). Think of it - if the compiler does not know the type, how it could check that your trait stack is correct?

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, I didn't say anything about variables, I am focused solely on resolution of `super` (this is not a variable). Besides I am afraid those comments become soon a chat, to preserve some order :-) I will no comment further. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I misunderstood what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> val queue = (new BasicIntQueue with Incrementing with Filtering)
> ```
>
> on p.229 or entire explanation of linearization (p.234) it seems to me, that super cannot be statically bound, because otherwise stacking traits would not be possible -- i.e. when class "starts" the chain of calling of stacked method with super already resolved, it would hit direct class parent no matter what user added to the stack of traits

But the chain in this case doesn't start with `BasicIntQueue`'s methods, but with `Filtering`'s. It only starts with the class if no mixed-in traits override the method. If you define instead

```
class MyQueue extends BasicIntQueue with Incrementing with Filtering {
  .. // some super calls
}
```

or

```
// an anonymous class
val queue = new BasicIntQueue with Incrementing with Filtering {
  .. // some super calls
}
```

`super` will refer to `BasicIntQueue with Incrementing with Filtering`, and this is resolved statically.

However, `super` calls in `Incrementing` are resolved dynamically: in `BasicIntQueue with Incrementing` they will refer to `BasicIntQueue`, while in `BasicIntQueue with Filtering with Incrementing` they will refer to `BasicIntQueue with Filtering`, without any changes in `Incrementing`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it -- it is problem with terminology. Because I thought of the linearization as of the setup for `super` resolution "table". Example -- let `MyQueue` extend only `BasicIntClass` and later declare `queue` variable as `new MyQueue with Incrementing with Filtering`. One can think that table for `super` is built right there (my understanding), however you could say `super` is fixed, and the order of the methods are built there.